# Change vertex and edge style

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, graphs, automation

I wanted the larger circle to be an ellipse, and the loop on the right to be smaller (as the below drawing shows). Does anyone know how to do it?

[image]

this is my .TEX document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}

\tikzset{->,
    >=stealth,
    node distance = 3cm,
    every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10},
    initial text = $I$}
\begin{document}    

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state, initial,accepting] (Q1) at (0,0) {$\{q_1\}$};
\node[state,accepting] (Q2) at (3,0) {$\{q_1,q_2,q_3\}$};

\draw
(Q1) edge [above] node [] {$a$} (Q2)
(Q2) edge [loop right] node [] {$a$} (Q2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

this is the output i got:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: thanks to [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647248/73317) (+1), I realized that I had not tried the obvious `ellipse` style (or `shape=ellipse`) correctly: I had only tried `\node[ellipse, state, ...` which doesn't give the expected result because, most probably, `state` implies the `circle` shape, thus overriding the `ellipse` style if used in this order. However, with `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}`, `\node[state, ellipse, ...` allows one to draw a state node with an elliptical shape. Therefore, the easiest way would be:

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  ->, >=stealth,
  node distance=3cm,
  every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10},
  initial text={$I$},
  ]
\node[state, initial, accepting] (Q1) at (0,0) {$\{q_1\}$};
\node[state, ellipse, accepting] (Q2) at (3,0) {$\{q_1, q_2, q_3\}$};

\draw (Q1) edge [above] node {$a$} (Q2);
\draw (Q2.10) .. controls +(40:3mm) and +(90:2mm) .. ([xshift=3.3mm] Q2.east)
  node[right] {$a$} .. controls +(-90:2mm) and +(-40:3mm) .. (Q2.-10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the loop, I obtained the best results by choosing Bézier control points manually, as in the preceding code.

The rest is my first idea that uses `\scalebox` and the `xscale` transformation in order to draw the elliptical state. It's a little bit more complicated, but gives good control over the size and eccentricity of the ellipse.

In order to keep the font shape inside your `(Q2)` node unchanged, I first horizontally scale the node contents by the inverse of the factor that I use to scale the whole `circle`-shaped node (0.5 × 2 = 1 → the text shape is unchanged).

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \scalebox
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  ->, >=stealth,
  node distance=3cm,
  every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10},
  initial text={$I$},
  ]
\node[state, initial, accepting] (Q1) at (0,0) {$\{q_1\}$};
\node[xscale=2, transform shape, state, accepting] (Q2) at (3,0) {%
  \scalebox{0.5}[1]{$\{q_1, q_2, q_3\}$}};

\draw (Q1) edge [above] node {$a$} (Q2);
\draw (Q2.20) .. controls +(45:4mm) and +(90:3mm) .. ([xshift=5mm] Q2.east)
  node[right] {$a$} .. controls +(-90:3mm) and +(-45:4mm) .. (Q2.-20);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Smaller loop:

```
\draw (Q2.20) .. controls +(40:3mm) and +(90:2mm) .. ([xshift=3.5mm] Q2.east)
  node[right] {$a$} .. controls +(-90:2mm) and +(-40:3mm) .. (Q2.-20);
```

[image]

Here is a simpler way for the loop, but it's a bit further from your drawing (the `in` and `out` angles are notably different; if you change them, the arrow will not start from and end at the same points on the node border):

```
\draw (Q1) edge [above] node {$a$} (Q2)
      (Q2) edge [loop right, looseness=4] node {$a$} (Q2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A variation of the first version of @frougon's answer. By defining `state` style as ellipse the MWE become more concise and clear:

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
                 > = Stealth,
     node distance = 7mm,
 every edge/.style = {draw, ->},
every state/.style = {ellipse, draw, thick, fill=gray!15,
                      minimum size=2em, inner xsep=0pt},
      initial text = {$I$},
                    ]
\node (Q1)  [state, initial, accepting] {$\{q_1\}$};
\node (Q2)  [state, accepting,
             right=of Q1] {$\{q_1, q_2, q_3\}$};
\draw   (Q1) edge ["$a$"] (Q2) 
        (Q2) edge [loop right, distance=9mm,"$a$"] (Q2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Stupid me who had tried `\node[ellipse, state, ...` but not `\node[state, ellipse...`. Gasp! :) Thanks for making me realize this.