# Reposition graph edges

Tags: graphs, automata, edge

How can I place the loop of vertex {q_1, q_2, q_3} and vertex {empty set} above and below these vertices, respectively (as in the drawing below), instead of on the right?

[image]

This is my .TEX:

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
->, >=stealth,
node distance=3cm,
every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10},
initial text={$I$},
]
\node[state, initial](Q1) at (0,0) {$\{q_1\}$};
\node[state,accepting] (Q3) at (6,0) {$\{q_4\}$};
\node[state] (V) at (0,-3) {$\varnothing$};
\node[xscale=2, transform shape,state] (Q2) at (3,0) {%
    \scalebox{0.5}[1]{$\{q_1,q_2,q_3\}$}};

\draw (Q1) edge [above] node {$a$} (Q2);
\draw (Q1) edge [left] node {$b,c$} (V);
\draw (Q2) edge [above] node {$b,c$} (Q3);
\draw (Q3) edge [below] node [pos = 0.44,below = 0.2] {$a,b,c$} (V);
\draw (V.20) .. controls +(40:3mm) and +(90:2mm) .. ([xshift=3.5mm] V.east)
node[right] {$a,b,c$} .. controls +(-90:2mm) and +(-40:3mm) .. (V.-20);
\draw (Q2.20) .. controls +(40:3mm) and +(90:2mm) .. ([xshift=3.5mm] Q2.east)
node[right] {$a$} .. controls +(-90:2mm) and +(-40:3mm) .. (Q2.-20);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You need to read about Bézier control points (or practice a few minutes in Gimp or Photoshop or...) then change the control points given after the `controls` keyword. `+(40:3mm)` is a relative polar coordinate: 40 degrees counter-clockwise from the ((0,0), (0,1)) “vector”, 3mm of radius (counted from the last point placed so far on the path). You also need to change the anchors saying where the small loops start from and end at: `(Q2.20)` is an anchor located on the border of node `(Q2)` at polar angle 20 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @frougon. This is a way to do it:

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
->, >=stealth,
node distance=3cm,
every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10},
initial text={$I$},
]
\node[state, initial](Q1) at (0,0) {$\{q_1\}$};
\node[state,accepting] (Q3) at (6,0) {$\{q_4\}$};
\node[state] (V) at (0,-3) {$\varnothing$};
\node[xscale=2, transform shape,state] (Q2) at (3,0) {%
    \scalebox{0.5}[1]{$\{q_1,q_2,q_3\}$}};

\draw (Q1) edge [above] node {$a$} (Q2);
\draw (Q1) edge [left] node {$b,c$} (V);
\draw (Q2) edge [above] node {$a$} (Q3);
\draw (Q3) edge [below] node [pos = 0.44,below = 0.2] {$a,b,c$} (V);
\draw (V.-115) .. controls +(-130:3mm) and +(180:2mm) .. ([yshift=-3.5mm] V.south)
node[below] {$a,b,c$} .. controls +(0:2mm) and +(-50:3mm) .. (V.-65);
\draw (Q2.100) .. controls +(130:3mm) and +(180:2mm) .. ([yshift=3.5mm] Q2.north)
node[above] {$b,c$} .. controls +(0:2mm) and +(50:3mm) .. (Q2.80);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is overly complicated. Just `\draw` from `(V)` to `(V)` and set `in=` and `out=` angles, together with `looseness`.

```
\draw (V)to[out=250, in=290, looseness=3]node[below] {$a,b,c$}(V);
\draw (Q2)to[out=110, in=70, looseness=2]node[above] {$b,c$}(Q2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647216/change-vertex-and-edge-style/647248#647248) on the your previous question:

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
                 > = Stealth,
     node distance = 11mm and 7mm,
 every edge/.style = {draw, ->},
every state/.style = {ellipse, draw, thick, fill=gray!15,
                      minimum size=2em, inner xsep=0pt},
      initial text = {$I$},
                    ]
\node (Q1)  [state, initial]        {$\{q_1\}$};
\node (Q2)  [state, right=of Q1]    {$\{q_1, q_2, q_3\}$};
\node (Q3)  [state, accepting,
             right=of Q2]           {$\{q_1\}$};
\node (Q4)  [state, below=of Q1]    {$\varnothing$};
\draw   (Q1) edge ["$a$"] (Q2)
        (Q2) edge [loop above, distance=7mm,"$a$"] (Q2)
        (Q2) edge ["$a$"]       (Q3)
        (Q1) edge ["${b,c}$"]   (Q4)
        (Q3) edge ["${a,b,c}$"] (Q4)
        (Q4) edge [loop left, distance=7mm,
                    "${a,b,c}$"] (Q4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]